# accessing elements from adjacent columns while iterating over an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I want to multiply the values of each element in a column of an `ndarray` by the value of the corresponding element in the next column. I can do this with `enumerate()`:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], np.int32)

[i*s[1, c] for c, i in enumerate(s[0])]
# [0, 4, 10]
```

but this feels hacky and it would be even hackier to to extend it to deeper `ndarrays`. Is there a better way to handle iteration like this in NumPy? I looked at `strides`, but it wasn't clear how to use that to get to another column.

Comment: `s[0] * s[1]` ?

Comment: Well, that's pretty elegant. Is this straight Python or does it take advantage of some NumPy overriding magic?

Comment: that's numpy - did you skip the numpy for beginners docs?

Comment: @highpost objects can implement what needs to happen when they get "multiplied", by defining their own `__mul__()` - it's Python, but a library like `numpy` has to take advantage of it, as it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.prod`.

Here docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], np.int32)
np.prod(s, axis=0)
```

Comment: This is a lot slower than just multiplying the two specific columns as OP indicates they need (and gives a different result if there's more than just the two columns they need multiplied) - the answer is so simple that @psidom managed it in an 11 character comment.

Comment: @Grismar, the OP talks about "deeper ndarrays", but clarify what that means.  What if `a` has more than 2 rows?  Or other dimensions.  `prod` may be overkill for this simple example,   `np.prod` is the multiplication equivalent of the widely used `np.sum`.